# Mac Mini SD card slot

Tags: 18.04, hardware, mac

I recently bought a mac mini and installed 18.04 on it. All of the hardware ports are recognized (including bluetooth) except for the SD card slot. I've tried a few solutions including editing the 'modules' file in the '/etc/' directory to include 'tifm_sd'.

Unfortunately I can't mount the card, I have a usb SD adapter that works, but the SD slot would move data much faster. If anybody has a solution, It would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1. `/etc/modules` is obsolete. Read `man modules-load.d` or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/modules-load.d.5.html  2. Rather than editing config files (a permanent solution), try it first with `modprobe`. 3. Does `lshw` see it?

Comment: `lshw` does show the sd card slot.

Comment: I used `modprobe tifm_sd` to no effect.  Just to make sure, I used `lsmod` and sure enough, `tifm_sd` is there.  I'm beginning to think this might be a hardware issue. I'd love to know if anyone else out there with a mac mini has the card slot functioning well.